# Auto type recognizing in interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface similar to this:

```
interface ValueGetter<T> {
    property: keyof T;
    getValueFunction: (value: any) => value;
}
```

I want to be able to provide a custom `getValueFunction` to access some property of `T`, I’m having trouble with defining the right type and substituting the `any`.

Given the following interface I need is:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const valueGetter: ValueGetter<Person> = {
    property: 'name',
    getValueFunction: … 
    // I want here the type checker to recognize that the
    // correct type of this function should be: (value: string) => string, because 
    // the property 'property' is 'name' and the type of Person['name'] is string.
}
```

If I want to access the other property `age`:

```
const valueGetter: ValueGetter<Person> = {
    property: 'age',
    getValueFunction: … Expected type: (value: number) => number
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want a union type like `type ValueGetter<T> = {[K in keyof T]: {property: K; getValueFunction: (value: T[K]) => T[K]}}[keyof T]`, but I don't understand why `getValueFunction()` should take the property and return it untouched.  What's the use case for that?  I could understand something like `(value: T) => T[K]`, which takes a `T` and returns the property value corresponding to the `property` key...  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this by adding the desired property key as a type argument to your `ValueGetter` interface.

So something like:

```js
interface ValueGetter<T, K extends keyof T> {
    property: K;
    getValueFunction: (value: T[K]) => T[K];
}

const valueGetter: ValueGetter<Person, 'age'> = {
    property: 'age', // here you can only enter 'age' now, nothing else
    getValueFunction: … Expected type: (value: number) => number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
interface ValueGetter<T,K extends keyof T> {
    property: K,
    getValueFunction: () => T[K];
}

interface Person {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}

const person : Person = {
    age: 25,
    name: "John"
}

const ageGetter : ValueGetter<Person, 'age'> = {
    property: 'age',
    getValueFunction: () => person[ageGetter.property]
}
```

This is as close I could come to what you needed. It's redundant with the propety declaration but it works. If you don't use `K`, TS will default to printing all propety types (so `number | string` in this case)